# Customize setup wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-project

How can I customize the setup installer with my custom dialogs? I am using the Setup Wizard Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Setup Wizard Project?  If so, right-click that project in the Solution Explorer, go to View -> User Interface. Now you can edit the default dialog (right-click properties) or add your own custom Dialog screens.